# Way to add ActsAsTaggable::Tag.all to seed file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, seeding

I have added about 450 tags locally using the Acts As Taggable gem.  I am trying to use seed:dump to add all the tags to the seeds file.  The issue is, these tags are not part of a model so seed:dump doesn't add them to the seeds file.  Is there a way I can do this?  I would just like to add them to the seeds file so another developer can add them to his system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the [gem seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) to run `rake db:seed:dump`, correct me if I'm wrong.

This solution works for versions of the gem seed_dump that are 3.0.0 or higher.

If you run `rails console` and in irb run

```
SeedDump.dump(ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all, file: 'db/seeds.rb', append: true)
```

That should add in your `db/seeds.rb`

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.create!([
  # Your tags
])
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I am getting an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'dump' for SeedDump:Module` when I run that commands.

Comment: What version of the seed_dump gem are you using? What version of rails are you using?

Comment: `rails 3.2.11` and `"~> 0.5.3"`

Comment: I was just looking through the gem, I don't think the method I referenced is available for version `0.5.3`, the earliest version that has that method is `3.0.0` (the latest version is `3.1.0`), sorry I couldn't be more helpful, I will update the answer so people know what gem version it works with